# Rails Backbone adding attributes work slow and buggy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm making a game with backbone. I made simple Stats page and adding stats. How i can improve it to work smoothly? Becouse now when i press "add 5 stats" , then i press "add health" 5 times, sometimes i have left 1-2 stats, sometimes i can add even more health, becouse stats decreases slower and i'm trying to add stats fast. Here is my View events page.

```
Sprint.Views.Stats ||= {}

class Sprint.Views.Stats.StatView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST["backbone/templates/stats/stat"]

  events:
    "click .add_health" : "add_health"
    "click .add_strength" : "add_strength"
    "click .add_stat" : "add_stat"

  tagName: "td"

  add_health: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    if @model.attributes.stat > 0
      @model.save(health: @model.attributes.health+1)
      @model.save(stat: @model.attributes.stat-1)
      @model.on("change", () => this.render() )

  add_strength: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    if @model.attributes.stat > 0
      @model.save(strength: @model.attributes.strength+1)
      @model.save(stat: @model.attributes.stat-1)
      @model.on("change", () => this.render() )

  add_stat: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    @model.save(stat: @model.attributes.stat+5)
    @model.on("change", () => this.render() )

  render: ->
    @$el.html(@template(@model.toJSON() ))
    return this
```

Here is my Template

```
Stats: <%= stat %><br>
Health: <%= health %><a href="#/<%= id %>/add_health" class="add_health"> add_health</a><br>
Strength: <%= strength %><a href="#/<%= id %>/add_strength" class="add_strength"> add_strength</a><br>
Make more stats: <a href="#/<%= id %>/add_stat" class="add_stat"> add 5 stat</a>
```

Where i can put my If's?

```
  add_exp: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    @model.save(experience: @model.attributes.experience+5)
    if @model.attributes.experience >= @model.attributes.level*30
      @model.save(level: @model.attributes.level+1, experience:     @model.attributes.experience-@model.attributes.level*30, stat: @model.attributes.stat+5)
    @model.on("change", () => this.render() )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call these two lines:

```
@model.save(health: @model.attributes.health+1)
@model.save(stat: @model.attributes.stat-1)
```

There is no guarantee which one will finish first, and the calls could be sending the model with the attributes not changed.

Instead, you should combine them into one save call:

```
@model.save({health: @model.attributes.health+1, stat: @model.attributes.stat-1})
```

This way, the model will be saved with both changes at the same time instead of two calls to the server that are racing.

Another note...

I would also move this line `@model.on("change", () => this.render() )` to an `initialize` function on the view, and not duplicate it in a lot of places where it is unneeded.  I may even change the syntax a bit...something like this:

```
initialize: ->
  @listenTo @model, 'change', @render
```

Comment: I edited my Post, on the end is my another event, how can i make an event which is allways looking for changes? Where to place The IF statement? Becouse now my levelUp works fine, but the next call adding 5 points is still buggy.

Comment: The problem is, you can't check the attributes of the model right after you call a save.  The save is an asynchronous call.  It does not wait until the save is completed to run the next command.  So when you save the attributes for experience and then try to check attributes.experience...you will still have the old value.  Try using a set.  model.set 'experience', model.attributes.experience + 5, then just call model.save {}.  This will set the attribute to the proper value, and the save can push that value to the server while still giving you access to the updated attribute.

Comment: Yes, works really much better, thx :) Would it be better to set on events and save+render on initialize? if yes, how to save model on initialize?

Comment: you can listen for a model change event and save everytime something changes, but that is a bit odd.  `listenTo model, 'change', some_function_that_saves_model_if_needed`